# Spark - How to keep max limit on number of values grouped in JavaPairRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata, rdd

I have an RDD like this:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String>
```

that has lot of entries and some keys are repeated lot of times. When I apply either `groupByKey` or `combineByKey`, its generating another

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<String>
```

Here is the problem, for some set of keys, the number of values is very huge (because particular keys are skewed). This is causing issue in further downstream consumption even produce memory issues.

My question is how to limit the number of values aggregated per key. I want to group by key, however the value list should not go beyond limit X number. Any overflowing values should be added to a new line, is there a way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you could use `map` on the rdd and remove the values where the list is too long.

Comment: I dont want to lose the values. I just want to keep it as new entry with same key and rest of values (overflowed values).

Comment: In that case, `flatMap` should be more suitable.

Comment: I could give you an answer using Scala (that you could covert to Java) if you want.

Comment: I am not sure how to split the values and create two entry of same key. If you give in scala, i would get some idea. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using `flatMap`. I'm not sure how to write it in Java, however, hopefully you can convert the Scala code. Code with example input:

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1, Iterable(1,2,3,4,5)), (2, Iterable(6,7,8)), (3, Iterable(1,3,6,8,4,2,7,8,3))))

val maxLength = 3
val res = rdd.flatMap{ case(id, vals) =>
  vals.grouped(maxLength).map(v => (id, v))
}
```

The idea is to split the list into a list of list where each inner list has a max length. Since, `flatMap` is used here the list of list will be flattened into a simple list which is the result you want. Using a max length of 3 and printing `res` gives:

```
(1,List(1, 2, 3))
(1,List(4, 5))
(2,List(6, 7, 8))
(3,List(1, 3, 6))
(3,List(8, 4, 2))
(3,List(7, 8, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful!